# How to write bypass css !important tag

Tags: jquery, css

I have a dropdown with the classes shown below. With jquery I am dynamically adding certain classes. But since `.dd-width` has `!important`, it is not taking the other **classes**. But I need to add other classes as well. IS there any way I can achieve this?

```
<select id="dd1" name="dd1" class=" dd-width required" >

.dd-width { width:350px !important; } 
.dd-mand {border: 3px solid #FF0004 !important;}
.dd-valid {border: 3px solid #28AF08!important;}
```

**JS:**

```
if (!input.val()) {
    input.addClass('dd-mand');
} else {
    input.addClass('dd-valid');
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to use !important ? You should never have to use it

Comment: `!important` basically overwrites other CSS your element may be inheriting from. The surest way to not have to use it any more is to ensure the other CSS which could provide styling for that element does not interfere

Comment: Never use !important. If it is the only way the CSS-command is working, you should figure out with firebug or chrome-developer tools why it is not working. 
You also could remove the other class by the .removeClass jQuery command. http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Comment: !important doesn't overwrite other CSS element inheritences, it adds the highest specific to it (which causes it to overwrite all other specifics)

Comment: Never use `important` for this very reason. The best solution available to you is to organise your CSS rules by specificity so that the correct one is always applied to the necessary element.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan **NEVER** is a wrong word, you should suggest ignoring `!important` unless required

Comment: @Mr.Alien I'd argue that `!important` is a hack that shouldn't even be in the CSS spec.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's not a hack, it is actually important to use important sometimes, I have real good experience in CSS, made 1000s of projects.. using `!important` at right place in a right way is actually good in some senarios

Comment: @Mr.Alien Me too. Although by properly organising my selectors I've never needed to use `!important` ;)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yea as far as specificity is concerned, we can always use specific selectors, but at some point, say error messages etc have consistent stylings, so at some places I do use `!important` especially when dealing with JS and modifying the dom on the flow :)

Answer (score 2):

Same problem as here:
[custom css being overridden by bootstrap css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768794/custom-css-being-overridden-by-bootstrap-css/19768934)

"CSS Specificity Calculator" article: http://specificity.keegan.st/

This answers everything you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `width` in the other `class` as well with `!important` keyword, also, if you can, use more specific selector instead of using a simple `class` selector.

```
select.dd-mand {
   /* Other styles */
   width: 100px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this

```
if (!input.val()) {
   input.removeClass('dd-valid');
   input.addClass('dd-mand');
 } else {
   input.removeClass('dd-mand');
   input.addClass('dd-valid');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your dd-mand and dd-valid class defines the same css property with !important. so when ever you will apply the dd-valid after the dd-mand the dd-mand border css rule will be applied first.

so the css class which is applied first to the element will have more priority than other in case of important.

so you have to remove the css class which you have applied first, then you have to apply another css class which defines same css rule.

if you don't want to do this. you can add inline style to that element by

```
$("selector").css("border", "border: 3px solid #28AF08!important");
```

because the inline style has more priority than the class.

thank u