# Custom CSS over Bootstrap CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap in a project and I want to center a text in some columns of my table.

So I use a class, specified in my  tag :

```
<td class="col_etat" rowspan="4"> MyContent </td>
```

In my CSS I have :

```
.col_etat {vertical-align: middle;}
```

And it doesn't work, we can see that the class in Bootstrap CSS is "over" my class :

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlSoW.png)

It works if I do it without a CSS, but it's not what I want :

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="4"> MyContent </td>
```

If someone knows what I have to do to make it works !

Comment: Can you fiddle your code

Comment: ".col_etat" could be "html body td.col_etat" to over-power bootstrap without using !important;, which is a bad idea and causes maintenance woes. you should only "go nuclear" and use !important after all else fail, ask any designer...

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity for info on how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to include styles.css file after bootstrap's CSS file.
You might also have to be more specific when defining .col_etat, just like Bootstrap is, so:

```
.table > tbody > tr > td.col_etat {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

There's a good article about CSS Specificity [here](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: You're right, it works, I didn't know I had to be more specific, thank's for your help !

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be an issue with specificity. See: [custom css being overridden by bootstrap css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768794/custom-css-being-overridden-by-bootstrap-css) for reference.

But in your case, the specificity of your styling class `.col_etat` is at 10, whereas the bootstrap `.table>thead>tr>th` is at 13, which is more specific than your styling.  You can specify more elements in your custom css in order to make your css override bootstrap's. I would try to avoid using !important if possible.

Comment: That's it ! I didn't know the "!important" keyword, but I won't use it, thank's for the advice !

Answer (score -3):

I always just edit the bootstrap css file.

Comment: -1 It is considered bad practice to edit core files for any framework/plugin