# Ng class not working for ng-table

Tags: css, angularjs, ngtable

```
I want to change background color of table row after selecting it. It works well for normal table. When i tried it to ng-table then only few styles are applied from ng-class not all styles are managed to apply including background color.
My [enter link description here][1]. 


  [1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/O6PzlHXEhOyheNS8BbAT?p=preview
```

I am giving working example for it on above link,
here ng class work for making font bold of row content but not changing row's background.

Comment: Please don't post code as an image; instead, copy the actual code into your question and ensure it's properly formatted. Also a JSFiddle or JSBin is always very useful: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not with ng-table. In fact problem is with class "table-striped" inside

```
"<table id="t1" ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">"
```

If you remove "table-striped", it works fine.

To go into the deep of how to override custom css over bootstrap css, you can follow below link. This link is very specific to this issue only.

[custom css being overridden by bootstrap css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768794/custom-css-being-overridden-by-bootstrap-css)

```
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768794/custom-css-being-overridden-by-bootstrap-css"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it was css specificity problem, i had to override css but css which i want to override has less specificity than earlier one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid $index in filtered lists. Try this instead:

```
        <tr ng-repeat="user in userLocations" ng-class="{'selected':user.selected}" ng-dblclick="deselectAll(); user.selected = true;">

    $scope.deselectAll = function(){
for(var i; i < userLocations.length i++;){
userLocations[i].selected = false;
}
}
```