# How to avoid bootstrap from overriding id-called custom css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want a div in my code to be horizontally center aligned, but also need to use bootstrap `col-md-12` class. So I used the following.

```
<div id="canvas" class="col-md-12">
```

And I declared css as:

```
#page-body #canvas {
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 60%;
}
```

However, this is being overridden by bootstraps float attribute:

```
.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
}
```

I don't wish to use the `!important` or change the bootstrap code.

When I was looking for solutions, I found that

1. Calling by id is suitable, which I have done without luck.
2. I tried [this problem's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768794/custom-css-being-overridden-by-bootstrap-css) using the specificity calculator which gave 200:10 results, but still not working.
3. My custom css link is placed after the bootstrap link

Is there a clean way to avoid this override?

The desired output is got when the `col-md-12` class is not used but I want to use the bootstrap class.

**UPDATE :** Basically using class `container` instead of `col-md-12` gave out the desired output, but does it have any side effects?
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sachid/papad3kr/)

Comment: You *did* try to give float:none; to #page-body #canvas, right?

Comment: Yes I did, but not what I wanted - bdw added an update to the question

Answer (score 2):

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 bg-danger">
            <h1>Middle</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This can be used as the answer for your requirement. Instead of using custom styles for making div centered horizontally you can use the **offset** style provided by bootstrap.

The class *bg-danger* is used for demonstration purpose only.

Answer (score 1):

Alright. Good question.

to override some crazy padding and margin provided by bootstrap, you could this,

```
*
{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

In order to use id or class, you could choose one of the following ways:

1)

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="canvas"></div>
</div>

.col-md-12
{
   //boostrap css will be here 
}
.col-md-12 #canvas
{
  //col-md-12 and canvas specific over here
 }
#canvas
{
  //all canvas specific goes here, any margin or padding mentioned here will override all the previous margin metioned!
}
```

2)

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="canvas">
      //put in your code here
    </div>
</div>


.canvas
{
//perform your styling here, all styles mentioned here will override the styles in col-md-12
}
```

Personally, I would prefer the second one. Reason being using id and class for styling purpose is not my thing, the code looks messy. I use class for coding and id for javascript purpose(like getting values).

Comment: It is the same as @Aaroniker 's asnwer and I have tried a jsfiddle to demmonstrate it.

Comment: @SachDan unable to load your JSFiddle!

Comment: bt i don't know how to add bootstrap to it though

Comment: use bootstrap links `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">` or u can create files in there as well! @SachDan

Answer (score 0):

It's always a bad idea to mix up styles with e.x. grid elements.
Just wrap the #canvas element:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="canvas"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using this caused the middle elements(two col-md-6's)  to go wild - i don't know how it happens though.