# Plotly graph component cannot accept viewport units to set text annotation font size

Tags: python, css, plotly, plotly-dash, viewport-units

I am using Plotly-Dash and need the font size of my text annotations to scale with the viewport width, as my graphs do. For various headers in my layout, I am able to directly set `font-size: '1vw'`, however `vw` is not an accepted unit for setting the `font-size` for the `style` attribute of a `dcc.Graph` component. Here is the associated traceback:

> ValueError: 
>       Invalid element(s) received for the 'size' property of scatter.textfont
>           Invalid elements include: ['1vw', '1vw', '1vw', '1vw', '1vw', '1vw', '1vw', '1vw', '1vw', '1vw']
>
> ```
> The 'size' property is a number and may be specified as:
>   - An int or float in the interval [1, inf]
>   - A tuple, list, or one-dimensional numpy array of the above
> ```

I figure that if the `dcc.Graph` component can accept viewport units (e.g. `style = {height: 30vw, width: 30vw}`) and simply convert them to pixels browser-side, then I should be able to perform a similar conversion with the `font-size`.

Is there a means on the Python side to retrieve the viewport width in pixels, so that I can perform my own scaling logic for the font size?

Here is a sample Dash application that demonstrates this behavior:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go

labels = {'Point 1': (3.5,5), 'Point 2': (1.5,2), 'Point 3': (3.5,8)}

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H1('Test', id='test', style={'margin': 50}),

    dcc.Graph(id='my-plot', style={'margin': 10}),

])

@app.callback(
    Output('my-plot', 'figure'),
    [Input('test', 'children')])
def update_graph(val):

    return {

        'data': [go.Scatter(
            x=[v[0]],
            y=[v[1]],
            text=k,
            mode='text'
        ) for k, v in labels.items()],

        'layout': go.Layout(
            margin={'l': 40, 'b': 40, 't': 40, 'r': 40},
            shapes=[
                {
                    'type': 'path',
                    'path': ' M 1 1 L 1 3 L 4 1 Z',
                    'fillcolor': 'rgba(44, 160, 101, 0.5)',
                    'line': {
                        'color': 'rgb(44, 160, 101)',
                    }
                },
                {
                    'type': 'path',
                    'path': ' M 3,7 L2,8 L2,9 L3,10, L4,10 L5,9 L5,8 L4,7 Z',
                    'fillcolor': 'rgba(255, 140, 184, 0.5)',
                    'line': {
                        'color': 'rgb(255, 140, 184)',
                    }
                },
            ]
        )
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: Can you provide sample running code with text annotations please?

Comment: if this problem is still relative at this moment, you can do a work around with javascript. just use an observer to check the viewport `width` of the browser in `px`, put that valua of `px` in an `let` and then apply that to the `font-size` of your `dcc.Graph`

Comment: Thank you for the responses thus far, I have added a sample Dash application that should serve as a working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understood from looking around, there is not a way of doing this using only `plotly-dash`.
What you need to achieve is essentially "responsive" typography, a topic which has some very interesting articles written about it:

- https://css-tricks.com/books/volume-i/scale-typography-screen-size/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/
- font-sizing using `em` units: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Ems

Dash offers the [option to override the default CSS and JS](https://dash.plot.ly/external-resources) of an app and you can see from the [layout documentation](https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started), how to use even external CSS files.

*My suggestion:* Research the resulting page to find how the text annotations get tagged (`id` and/or `class`) and use the methods provided in the articles above to create a satisfying result. (I am sorry that I cannot really do much more than suggesting, but I have not seen an example of your code :/)

---

**EDIT (after comment and question editing):**

So since the text annotations have the class `textpoint` we are going to [override the default CSS](https://dash.plot.ly/external-resources):

1. Create the suggested folder structure:

   ```
   - app.py
   - assets/
   |--- typography.css
   ```
2. On the `typography.css` apply one of the methods mentioned above (I am going by the 2nd bulleted example):

   ```
   .textpoint{
       font-size: calc(14px + (26 - 14) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
   }
   ```

---

**EDIT #2:**

I found the problem and a workaround to it:

- The method to add custom CSS on Dash version >= 0.22 is indeed the above and it works.
- The element that we need to target in order to apply our custom rule to the annotations is a `text` tag inside the `.textpoint` class (CSS syntax: `.textpoint text`)
- For some reason, the custom CSS rule gets overridden (probably for a similar reason, explained on the top answer of this SO post: [custom css being overridden by bootstrap css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768794/custom-css-being-overridden-by-bootstrap-css)). So we need the "nuclear" option of `!important`.

Utilizing the above, the `typography.css` should look like this:

```
.textpoint text{
  font-size: calc(14px + (26 - 14) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300))) !important;
}
```

Comment: I've added a sample Dash application to my post. Thank you for your thoughtful response thus far. It appears that the text annotations are tagged w/ `class="textpoint"`

Comment: @rahlf23 Thank you for the update, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me for some reason. In your answer above, that is the complete contents of the `typography.css` file correct?

Comment: Are you able to produce a working Dash application on your end where the text annotations actually resize with viewport width? They are not on my end, unfortunately.

Comment: @rahlf23 You should remove the `external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']` and the `external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets` part of the app init, because the instructions on that external CSS probalby overrides the custom one?

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well. Good suggestion though. I believe the external stylesheets are overwritten by the loaded assets .css files anyway...in any case, I updated my OP to reflect that.

Comment: @rahlf23 I found the problem and a workaround to it (added it on my answer).

Comment: You sir, deserve a medal. Thank you for putting this level of effort into your answer. Perfect workaround.

Comment: @rahlf23 Happy to help, it was an interesting investigation for me as well :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message says you should mention the size as an `int` object.
If you can't directly use vw in your code, try to get it using PySide / PyQt, and then convert it to `int` and save it under a different variable `width` & `height` that you can insert instead of `vw`.

```
from PySide import QtGui
#replace that with "from PyQt4 import QtGui" if you're using PyQt4

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
screen_resolution = app.desktop().screenGeometry()
width = int(screen_resolution.width())
height = int(screen_resolution.height())
```

I don't know what code you are working with so I haven't tried it out. Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am interested in the viewport size not the screen resolution dimensions, but thank you for your answer.